# PHP cURL - Illegal Characters Found in URL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to force a download using the URL from the database. The URL from the database is a external URL.

Using cURL, I'm trying to check if the URL is still alive like so:

```
$id = strip_tags($_GET['dl']);

// grab stuff from db
$resource = $engine->runQuery("SELECT downloadurl, section FROM resources WHERE id=:id");
$resource->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
$row = $resource->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// define memberonly sections
$memberonly = array(18, 7, 16, 19, 12);

if(in_array($row['section'], $memberonly)) {
    if($engine->isLoggedin()) {
        $dlurl = $row['downloadurl'];
        $filename = basename($dlurl);

        // curl lookup
        $curl = curl_init($dlurl);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_exec($curl);
        $retcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);

        if($retcode == 200) { // exists
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\""); 
            readfile($dlurl);
            exit;
        } elseif($retcode == 404) {
            echo 'File does not exist.';
        } else {
            echo 'Server is busy. Please try again later.';
        }
    } else {
        // head to root
        header('Location: /');
    }
}
```

cURL kept returning `0`, so I used `var_dump(curl_error($curl));` to see what the problem is. It outputs:

> string(31) "Illegal characters found in URL"

This is what the database URL looks like:

> http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/ppkgo/prod/CUSA00663_00/12/f_d2245740342e84367b73efbbf753a26de0aecbd69e6a494f1bdf4626cb52d3cc/f/UP0001-CUSA00663_00-AC5GAMEPS4000001-A0105-V0100_1.pkg

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to [urlencode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the `$dlurl` before passing it to curl?

Comment: @mkasberg Yes, that returns `Could not resolve: [...] (Misformatted doma`

Comment: this is what the url looks like is not enough, there could be hidden characters everywhere. E.g. \r at the end. I recommend detailed investigation by e.g. printing the hex characters of this variable.

Comment: have you checked to see if there's a hidden `newline` at the end of the URL ??  `\n` or `\r`  --  You should be able to `trim ` if so --> `$url = trim($url);`

Comment: @Zak Yes, there is a hidden space at the end of the download url. I've trimmed the download url but that returns `malformed`

Comment: Are you really going to download a 2.1 GB file onto your server and then serve it to the client every single time they reload the page? Ouch. Why not do a `header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url)); die();`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo That's probably a better solution indeed, and it works. If you can post that as an answer, I'll mark this as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as the file is 2.1 GB even with caching you'd have an insane first-time download time and your PHP would probably wait quite a while `((2.1 * 1024) / (100 / 8)) = at least 2.86 minutes at a 100 mbit/s connection + php overhead + hdd write time` before even *starting* the file download for the user (as your server has to download it first).

Since you have an URL to the asset you're better off just forwarding the user there by using:

```
$url = 'http://gs2.ww.prod.dl.playstation.net/gs2/ppkgo/prod/CUSA00663_00/12/f_d2245740342e84367b73efbbf753a26de0aecbd69e6a494f1bdf4626cb52d3cc/f/UP0001-CUSA00663_00-AC5GAMEPS4000001-A0105-V0100_1.pkg';

header(sprintf('Location: %s', $url));
die();
```

---

Pros:

- Download is MUCH faster for the user as they don't have to wait for your server to download the file first
- You avoid using up your bandwidth (at LEAST 4.2 GB for the first user - first download then upload to the user)
- PHP has way less overhead
- You won't fill up your local server with cached files

Cons:

- Your users can see the origin of the files (is this really an issue?)
- They (playstation.net) will know the request came from you (they can see that in the referrer). You can use services like https://dereferer.me/ to avoid this, if you really need it.

---

It essentially makes the flow go from:

```
1. user
2.   your web server
3.     PHP
4.       playstation.net
5.     PHP
6.   your web server
7. user
```

to

```
1. user
2.   playstation.net
3. user
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this Line `$dlurl = urlencode($dlurl);`after `$filename = basename($dlurl);`

like below:

```
$dlurl = $row['downloadurl'];

$filename = basename($dlurl);

$dlurl = urlencode($dlurl);
```

Also try this to remove unexpected charecter from your url:

```
$dlurl  = str_replace(' ', '', $dlurl ); // remove spaces
$dlurl = str_replace("\t", '', $dlurl ); // remove tabs
$dlurl = str_replace("\n", '', $dlurl ); // remove new lines
$dlurl = str_replace("\r", '', $dlurl ); // remove carriage returns
```

final code can be like below:

```
$dlurl = $row['downloadurl'];
$dlurl  = str_replace(' ', '', $dlurl ); // remove spaces
$dlurl = str_replace("\t", '', $dlurl ); // remove tabs
$dlurl = str_replace("\n", '', $dlurl ); // remove new lines
$dlurl = str_replace("\r", '', $dlurl ); // remove carriage returns
$filename = basename($dlurl);
```

if you do this no need `urlencode.`

Comment: $dlurl = $row['downloadurl'];
$dlurl = trim($dlurl);
$filename = basename($dlurl);
$dlurl = urlencode($dlurl);

if it not work try this: 
$dlurl = $row['downloadurl'];
$dlurl = trim($dlurl);
$filename = basename($dlurl);

>> Main problem is that when you are collecting URL it adding "\r"
that is not allowed in URL. you should remove "\r" somehow.

Comment: You can try this also tor remove unexpected charecters:

$dlurl = str_replace('.', '', $dlurl ); // remove dots
$dlurl = str_replace(' ', '', $dlurl ); // remove spaces
$dlurl = str_replace("\t", '', $dlurl ); // remove tabs
$dlurl = str_replace("\n", '', $dlurl ); // remove new lines
$dlurl = str_replace("\r", '', $dlurl ); // remove carriage returns

Comment: Thank you for your help. I went with h2ooooooo's solution, since that's less excessive for the server, and works.